# How to set DataGrid's BindingSource via XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using DataGrid bound to List property in my user control:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" .... 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSorce, ElementName=UserControl}" 
                            ....>
```

My problem is that I need it updated every time I change the source.

I had the user control implement INotifyPropertyChanged and do raise PropertyChanged event, but the DataGrid original content remains the same.

I've read that for the DataGrid to change, I should set BindingSource between ItemSorce and the binding, but all examples I've seen are doing this via c# source code.

How do I set BindingSource via xaml, and is this the best way to synchronize the DataGrid and ItemSorce?

Comment: Any WPF control displaying a collection should be bound against an `ObservableCollection<>`

Comment: @Matten: you're right. I've changed the type to observable collection and it works.

Comment: @ArsenZahray If added it as answer so you can close your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ObservableCollection<>` instead of a `List<>` as it is designed for bindings.